# Image and div sections are cut off when browser size is decreased

Tags: css, html

On the website I'm building, after I decrease the size of the browser, the header images and div sections are just cut off: [image]

I've tried tracing the code using Firebug, but I really can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

CSS:

```
.slide {
    padding-top: 125px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 960px;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 10px 10px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
div#home, div#contact  {
    min-height: 480px;
 }
div#inner-container {
    text-align: left;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    white-space: normal;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
 }
 div#greenPortion {
    background-color: #3CA67B;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
 }
 div#title {
    background-image:url(../images/banner.png);
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
 }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="slide" id="home" data-slide="1" data-stellar-background-ratio="1">
        <div id="inner-container">
            <div id="name" clas="row">
                <img src="images/names.png">
            </div>                            
        </div>
        <div id="greenPortion"></div>
    </div>
```

Website: http://andrewgu12.kodingen.com/

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by cut off? Looking at your code, you seem to have an understanding of percentages vs. explicitly set width. Do you mean your media queries aren't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `min-width: 960px` to your `body` in css:

**CSS**

```
body {
    ...
    min-width: 960px;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a width in percentage to make the elements adjust to the window size

```
div#inner-container {
    width: 100%;
}

div#header {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Also you should look into using media queries to adjust the look of your site at different screen resolutions